How to deal with WHERE clause dynamically if no input parameters were sent from client
Basically this is the flow.
Client from REST API
GET http://localhost:8080/app-context/classroom/?studentid=1&teacherid=1&classroomno=1


studentid is an optional field
teacherid is an optional field
classroomno is an options field

This call is made from the controller to the service layer.
This is the controller:
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/app-context")
public class MyApplicationController {

    @Autowired
    private ClassRoomFetcherService classRoomFetcherService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/classroom", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> getClassRoomDetails(
        @RequestParam(value = "studentid", required = true) String studentid,
        @RequestParam(value = "teacherid", required = false) String teacherid,
        @RequestParam(value = "classroomno", required = false) String classroomno
        ) {
        try {
            List<ClassRoomData> data = classRoomFetcherService.getchDetails(studentid, teacherid, classroomno);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(data, HttpStatus.OK);
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("operation failed", e);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }

}

This is the service:
@Service
public class ClassRoomFetcherService {

    @Autowired
    private ClassRoomRepo classRoomRepo;

    public List fetchDetails(Long studentid, Long teacherid, Long classroomno){
        return return classRoomRepo.pullData(studentid, teacherid, classroomno);
    }
}

This is the repository interface:
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface ClassRoomRepo extends JpaRepository<ClassRoomData, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT * from class_room_data WHERE std_id= :studentid AND tchr_id = :teacherid AND cls_room_no= :classroomno" ,nativeQuery = true)
    List<ClassRoomData> pullData(@Param("studentid") Long studentid, @Param("teacherid") Long teacherid, @Param("classroomno") Long classroomno);

}

My use cases are

GET http://localhost:8080/app-context/classroom/?studentid=1&teacherid=1&classroomno=1
GET http://localhost:8080/app-context/classroom/?studentid=1&teacherid=1
GET http://localhost:8080/app-context/classroom/?studentid=1
GET http://localhost:8080/app-context/classroom/

The problem with this is since I cannot manage the WHERE clause in a single method dynamically, or else it eventually ends up in writing different versions of the method which are specifically used with regard to input parameters. Do you have any suggestions of design pattern I can use?

You can use JPA Specification.
Define your repository as
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<ClassRoomData, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<ClassRoomData> {}

Then you need to create specification:
        var spec = new Specification<ClassRoomData>() {
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<ClassRoomData> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
                List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
                if (studentId != null) {
                    predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("stdId"), studentId));
                }
                return cb.and(predicates.toArray(Predicate[]::new));
            }
        };


You can add handling of other parameters.
Then you call repository
List<ClassRoomData> result = customerRepository.findAll(spec);

More examples you can find here.

Thanks @talex for correction  and help. but actually I am using native query with multiple table with JOIN clause, I missed that query. updating again.

That is not a problem. API is quite flexible. You can do all you can do in SQL.

Problem I am facing is WHERE clause without any input parameters from client, ending up in SQLGrammerException.

You should ask about it. I hear there is good site for that kind of question :)

I think this works for me, thanks for helping out :)
